# misconception about pointwise/uniform convergence

Tags: uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence

Can anyone clear up the misconception in my argumentation.
If a sequence of functions $f_k(x)$ is pointwise convergent towards some limit $f(x)$ for every $x$, then at every point $x$ we can choose an arbitrary distance $\varepsilon$ such that from a follow index $n_0$ the distance of $f_k(x)$ with $k\ge n_0$ and $f(x)$ is smaller than $\varepsilon$. So why can't we take the maximum $K$ of all the $n_0$ regarding to all the $x$ and say from this $K$ we have $|f_k(x) - f(x)| < \varepsilon$ for every $x$ which means that $\sup_x |f_k(x) - f(x)|<\varepsilon$ for $k>K$? Is the reason that since the set of all these indices $n_0$ regarding to all the $x$ is overcountable and so a maximum does not exist?

Comment: "we can choose an arbitrary distance epsilon": it is not about choosing it, it is about dealing with an arbitrary one given to you. Also, you are right in your main point, it is possible "a maximum does not exist"

Comment: The best is to work out explicitly  a simple example of non uniform convergence (take functions that are constant zero on $[0,1/2+1/n] \cup [1/2+2/n,1]$ and a symmetric triangle of area $1$ on $[1/n,2/n]$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the sequence of functions $f_n(x)=x^n$ defined on $(0,1)$, with limit function $f(x)=0$. Say we try to satisfy the definition of uniform convergence with $\epsilon=0.1$. We have $|f_n(x)-f(x)|=x^n$ and so we want $x^n<0.1$.

For $x=0.9$ we can take $n=22$ since then $(0.9)^{22}<0.1$.

For $x=0.99$ we can take $n=230$ since $(0.99)^{230}<0.1$.

For $x=0.999$ we can take $n=2302$ since $(0.999)^{2302}<0.1$.

Clearly there is no $N$ we can take which would work for all $x\in(0,1)$. That is, given $x$ we need $n(x)>\log_{x}0.1$ and as $x$ approaches $1$ the values of $n(x)$ approach infinity.

Another way of putting this is that, as you say, we cannot take the maximum of the set of all $n$'s, simply because that set is infinite. A maximum is guaranteed to exist for finite sets, but not for infinite ones, and indeed the maximum does not exist in this example, as the above calculation shows.